# Which software to use for continuous integration of a Java web project

Tags: java, continuous-integration

We're in an early stage of a new web project. The project will grow and become complex over time. From the beginning we will have unit and integration tests using JUnit and system tests using HtmlUnit. We might also add some static code analysis tools to the build process if they prove to be of value to us.

If you're or have been involved in a project which uses continuous integration. Which software do/did you use and do you think it has payed off? Which software would you recommend for continuous integration of a Java web project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hudson (the best). [Hudson Website](http://hudson-ci.org/)

Answer (score 2):

JetBrains TeamCity Pro.  http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/index.html

The Professional Edition does not require any license key. TeamCity starts running automatically with the Professional Edition Server if no license key is entered in the program. A single Professional Edition Server installation grants the rights to setup:

3 Build Agents at no additional cost 
20 User Accounts 
20 Build Configurations

Answer (score 2):

Having used both [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) and [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) , I can recommend Hudson as the easier of the two to config (easily done via the web GUI, though direct configfile editing is also supported).

Answer (score 1):

Hudson is great and free:
http://hudson.dev.java.net/

Bamboo is great but costs $$
http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/

Answer (score 0):

I've been very pleased with [Atlassian's Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/). Even though it is commercial, the Starter Pack license is just $10 for 10 users. It's very well documented, easy to set up and flexible.

Answer (score -1):

CruiseControl works reasonably well once you get it configured.

http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -1):

[CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/)

> CruiseControl is both a continuous integration tool and an extensible framework for creating a custom continuous build process. It includes dozens of plugins for a variety of source controls, build technologies, and notifications schemes including email and instant messaging. A web interface provides details of the current and previous builds. And the standard CruiseControl distribution is augmented through a rich selection of 3rd Party Tools.

Answer (score -1):

I've used [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) for Java projects, and [CruiseControl.NET](http://ccnet.thoughtworks.com/) for .NET projects, and both work great.

I setup CruiseControl for a project that's been running for 4 years with several dozen developers, and while the configuration has been tweaked several times in the interim, it works great.  (I don't actively support that project anymore, but I still work with the people who do.)

In my current position, CruiseControl.NET is being used to support several .Net projects, and has been used for 2+ years.

Comment: Apparently someone doesn't like CruiseControl, and so they went through a set of 3-year-old answers and downvoted the ones that recommended CruiseControl.  That was mature.